# Viewbag getting null value

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view

I have two Controllers  ResultController and HomeController.
From Result Controller's Index ActionResult I am passing parameter value via ViewBag to view

```
public IActionResult Index(string listingType, string location, string viewType, [FromQuery] SearchModel searchModel)
        {
            SearchQuery model = new SearchQuery(searchModel, location, this.cacheService);
            var locationList = this.searchFactory.GetSearchService(model.ListingType).GetSearchResults(model, listingType);
            ViewBag.listingType = listingType;
            ViewBag.location = location;
            ViewBag.viewType = viewType;
            ViewBag.searchModel = searchModel;
            return View(locationList);
        }
```

Now In View received values via viewbag and passing the values to Homecontroller's PropertyDetails

```
@Html.ActionLink(linkText: "Comfortable Apartment in Palace", "PropertyDetails", "Home", new { ListingId = pl.ListingId, listingType= ViewBag.listingType, location= ViewBag.location, viewType= ViewBag.viewType , searchModel= ViewBag.searchModel }, null)
```

In Homecontroller's PropertyDetails

```
public IActionResult PropertyDetails(string listingType, string location, string viewType, [FromQuery] SearchModel searchModel, int ListingId)
        {
            SearchQuery model = new SearchQuery(searchModel, location, this.cacheService);
            var locationList = this.searchFactory.GetSearchService(model.ListingType).GetSearchResults(model, listingType);
            var result = locationList.SalesList.FirstOrDefault(s=>s.ListingId==ListingId);
            return View(result);
        }
```

In PropertyDetails I am getting all the parameter values which was passed by viewbag but searchmodel parameter is null.Could anyone please tell me why am I getting null in searchmodel
parameter? and is there any alternative approach to pass value ?

Searchmodel class

```
public class SearchModel
    {
        public string PI { get; set; }
        public string SIMP { get; set; }
        public string L { get; set; }
        public string S { get; set; }
        public int[] LocationId;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@{
    var LocationId = (new int[] { 1, 2, 3 });
}
@Html.ActionLink("Comfortable Apartment in Palace", "PropertyDetails", "Home", new { ListingId = 1, listingType = 2, location = 3, viewType = 4, L = "L", PI = "PI", S = "S", SIMP = "SIMP", Locations = string.Join(",", LocationId) }, null)
```

SearchModel class

```
public class SearchModel
    {
        public string PI { get; set; }
        public string SIMP { get; set; }
        public string L { get; set; }
        public string S { get; set; }
        public int[] LocationId;
        public string Locations { get; set; }
    }
```

Correct:

```
new {  L = "L", PI = "PI", S = "S", SIMP = "SIMP" }
```

Wrong

```
 new { searchModel= ViewBag.searchModel }
```

Comment: This is a code only answer, please describe what makes this work and what the OP did wrong.